# Transfer Data of type geography to a different server

Tags: sql-server-2008, geography

I have a local database with some data of type geography in it. I tried to use export wizard to copy the table to the target server, but get the error "Unknown coversion..".

SSIS-conversion file: C:\Programme\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\binn\DtwTypeConversion.xml.

Is there an easy way to gert this data over to the target server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated SqlInsert tool to now support geography data.

http://sqlinserter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to convert the geography data to WKB while transferring it to the target server. Requires some additional work but is still pretty fast.

If database administration is not a problem in your case transferring the data using linked servers would be your other option. Don't forget to use the OPENQUERY function though or you get the same conversion error.